# Modeling spatial correlations with multilevel data

Tags: r, regression, classification, spatial, multilevel-analysis

I have ~5M records of spatial polar coordinates (r and theta). These 5M records are from 400 different 'locations' that I have ~150 variables for (no NAs). I also have 1 binary variable used to flag each record as a Point of Interest or not. For the records that are not a POI, I have another variable giving more details on its type.

Of those 5M records, about 20k are 'Point of Interest'.

I want to examine the spatial relationships between these points of interest and the other points, and ultimately build a prediction model for whether they are in the same spatial cluster.

I have used DBSCAN to build spatial clusters to determine if these points of interest are near 'not points of interest' with success.  Now, I want to build a predictive model on whether a point of interest will be clustered with a point of interest using all levels of the data available.

My data levels are as follows (from high to low):
Location: 150 continuous variables
Clusters: 1 binary variable-- is there a POI in the cluster? (This is my response variable)
Points: 1 variable descriptor for non-points of interest

My question is what sort of modeling I should use to determine if a fairly accurate prediction model can be built. If not, I would like to classify the clusters as best as possible with the data available.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to move forward? I just need to be pointed in the right direction-- I assume I want to use some sort of multilevel analysis.

Thanks

PS- I use R, but have access to SAS if there is something only it can do.

Comment: You want a spatial Poisson model or kriging model.